# Android JNI error: Call function with boolean argument causes a crash

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm Trying to call this `JAVA` function:

```
public String getPreferredLanguage(boolean withRegion)
```

With `JNI` `GetMethodID`, But i always get a crash, i tried a lot of variations about the function signature in the `JNI` section, but none seemed to be helping.

The `JNI` code:

```
methodID getPreferredLanguageMethod = env->GetMethodID(languageServiceClass, "getPreferredLanguage", "(Ljava/lang/Boolean;Z)Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (!getPreferredLanguageMethod) {
        TTLOGD("LanguageService::getPreferredLanguage: ERROR getPreferredLanguageMethod is null\n");
    }
```

The crash message:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/tabtale/mobile/acs/services/LanguageService;.getPreferredLanguage(Ljava/lang/Boolean;Z)Ljava/lang/String;"
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: One of your calls into Java before the the call that is generating the error has thrown a Java exception (on the Java side).  You need to allow this Java exception to be processed (or process it yourself) before making any more JNI method calls. See the Java Exceptions section in: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after reading [this](https://communities.ca.com/docs/DOC-99575135) document over and over, i found my problem, and this is how the `JNI` function should be:

```
jmethodID getPreferredLanguageMethod = env->GetMethodID(languageServiceClass, "getPreferredLanguage", "(Z)Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Comment: Don't try to figure these things out for yourself. `javap -s` will tell you with 100% accuracy.

Comment: @EJP What do you run `javap` on?  What directory?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky From its _man_, `javap [options] class ...` so `javap -s ClassContainingRelevantMethod.class`